# How do I compare two letters in 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
array db 13,10,10,"pineapple $"
lea si, array+2
mov al, [si]
cmp al, 'A'
```

Here, are the string values first converted to ascii and then compared?
Also, what does 13, 10 and 10 imply?
Shouldn't array+0 and array+1 contain the total size and actual size of the string respectively?

Comment: What might "convert to ASCII" involve?

Comment: There's no conversion. You're simply comparing two bytes. One has the value 10 and the other has the value `'A'` (==65 ==0x41).

Comment: The `'p'` is at `array+3`. There are three bytes before it: 13, 10, and another 10.

Comment: 13,10 could be anything. But in the context of strings it usually means the character sequence CR, LF (i.e. Carriage Return followed by Linefeed).

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming a string memory layout similar to Pascal (with a max string length of 255). But in assembly, there is no "string" datatype. It's just a sequence of bytes, whatever meaning you like to assign to it.

Comment: Yes, character constants like `'A'` in the asm source are converted to binary by the assembler at assemble time.  Writing `'A'` is exactly equivalent to writing `65` or `41h`.

Comment: Also, that won't assemble.  You probably meant `array db 13,10,10, ...`, with the DB directive (Data Bytes) telling the assembler to assemble the following bytes into the output at that position.

Comment: "Shouldn't array+0 and array+1 contain the total size and actual size of the string respectively?" May be that you are thinking about the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah which uses that kind of data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line like `array db 13,10,10,"pineapple $"` creates a string of **bytes** in memory:

```
13, 10, 10, 112, 105, 110, 101, 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 32, 36
```

In 16-bit programming, when you see a string that ends with a $ character, it's very probable that it is a string meant to get outputted by the DOS.PrintString function 09h. The $ character acts like a terminator; it isn't actually outputted. In this example, the bytes in front are one CarriageReturn (13) and two LineFeeds (10). A carriage return brings the cursor back to the left edge of the screen, and a linefeed makes the cursor descend one line on the screen. In this case the cursor will descend two lines.

The instruction `lea si, array+2` loads the `SI` register with the offset address for the 3rd byte in the string. As you can see, that byte is not a true character, but rather what we call a **control code**. Some other control codes are 7 for BELL and 8 for BACKSPACE.

```
13, 10, 10, 112, 105, 110, 101, 97, 112, 112, 108, 101, 32, 36
^       ^
array   SI
```

The instruction `mov al, [si]` loads that byte into the `AL` register that in this case now holds the value 10.

The instruction `cmp al, 'A'` compares that value 10 from `AL` with the **number 65**. It's a number because the assembler will automatically translate the uppercase character 'A' into its equivalent ASCII code which is 65.

---

> How do I compare two letters in 8086?

If the character case is not important aka **case insensitive**, we need to make sure that both operands of the `cmp` instruction are using the same case.

eg. Looking for any of the uppercase characters from 'A' to 'Z' held in `DL`

```
 lea si, array+3 ; Position of the 1st true character
.loop:
 mov al, [si]
 cmp al, 'a'
 jb  .cont
 cmp al, 'z'
 ja  .cont
 sub al, 32      ; Convert from 'a' to 'z' into 'A' to 'Z'
.cont:
 cmp al, dl      ; Compare with one of 'A' to 'Z'
 ...
```

If the character case is important aka **case sensitive**, the `cmp` instruction can be used straight away.

eg. Looking for the character 'A' (So will not find 'a')

```
 lea si, array+3 ; Position of the 1st true character
.loop:
 mov al, [si]
 cmp al, 'A'
 ...
```